# Issue with cudafft library and fftshift on odd image dimensions

Tags: image-processing, fft, frequency-spectrum, ifft, c++

I'm facing with a code I'm implementing for an exam using the GPU. Specifically, the code I'm writing is in C++, and I'm using the CUFFT library to perform the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). The purpose of the project is to resize images that have both even and odd dimensions. The current steps I am taking are as follows:

1. Perform FFT with CUFFT.
2. Shift low frequencies to the center of the spectrum.
3. Crop the center of the Fourier spectrum using a square mask with dimensions equal to cropping dimensions of the image.
4. Perform inverse FFT shift.
5. Perform IFFT again with CUFFT.

The problem is: when processing square images with odd dimensions, even without using the GPU kernel for image resizing (executing only steps 1-2-4-5), the resulting image appears with colors that do not correspond to reality. I am attaching the code in which I perform the FFT shift on square images with odd dimensions and the obtained result.

Could someone help me identify the reason behind this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



//bool forward is true in fftshift in forward sense, otherwise is false.
__global__ void fftshift(cufftDoubleComplex *im, int height, int width, bool forward)
{
    int x, y, indshift;
    cufftDoubleComplex c;

    int idy = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; //columns
    int idx = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;  //rows
    int ind = idx + idy*width; 
    // input sizes
    int sx = width;
    int sy = height;

    // size of top-left quadrant
    int cx = forward ? (sx + 1) / 2 : sx / 2;
    int cy = forward ? (sy + 1) / 2 : sy / 2;

     if(idx < cy && idy < width) 
      {
        if(idx<cy && idy<cx) 
        {
            x=idx+cy;
            y=idy+ cx;
        }
        else if(idx<cy && idy>=cx) 
        {
            x=idx+cy; 
            y=idy- cx;
        }

       indshift = x+y*width;

        c.x = im[ind].x;
        c.y = im[ind].y;

        im[ind].x = im[indshift].x;
        im[ind].y = im[indshift].y;

        im[indshift].x = c.x;
        im[indshift].y = c.y;


    }

}

int main() {
    
    int in_max,in_min;
    cufftHandle planZ2Z, planIZ2Z;
    ofstream fp;

    // Read input image using OpenCV
    cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("donnaD.jpg", 0);

    if (inputImage.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Couldn't read the input image." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Get input image dimensions
    int inputWidth = inputImage.cols;
    int inputHeight = inputImage.rows;

    
    cufftDoubleComplex* h_input  = (cufftDoubleComplex * )malloc(inputHeight*inputWidth*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));  
    cufftDoubleComplex* h_output  = (cufftDoubleComplex * )malloc(inputHeight*inputWidth*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));  

    cufftPlan2d(&planZ2Z, inputHeight, inputWidth, CUFFT_Z2Z);
    cufftPlan2d(&planIZ2Z, inputHeight, inputWidth, CUFFT_Z2Z);


    // Find minimum and maximum values
    in_max=  static_cast<int>(inputImage.at<uchar>(0, 0));
    in_min = static_cast<int>(inputImage.at<uchar>(0, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputImage.cols; ++j) {
            int pixel_value = static_cast<int>(inputImage.at<uchar>(i, j));

            if (pixel_value < in_min) {
                    in_min = pixel_value;
            }

            if (pixel_value > in_max) {
                    in_max = pixel_value;
            }
        }
    }

  printf("height : %d, width %d", inputHeight,inputWidth);
  printf("\nMax value: %d\n",in_max);
  printf("\nMin value: %d\n",in_min);

  fp.open("input_donnaD.txt",ios::out);
  for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.rows; ++i) {
     for (int j = 0; j < inputImage.cols; ++j) {
            fp<< (int)inputImage.at<uchar>(i,j)<<" ";
    }
    fp<<"\n";
  }
  fp.close();

    for(int i=0;i<inputHeight;i++)
    {  
        for(int j=0;j<inputWidth;j++)
        {
            h_input[i * inputWidth + j].x = (double) inputImage.at<uchar>(i,j);
            h_input[i * inputWidth + j].y = 0.0f;
        
        }
  }

    // Allocate memory for input and padded output on the device
    cufftDoubleComplex* d_input, *d_output, *FI;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_input, inputWidth * inputHeight * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_output, inputWidth * inputHeight * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));
    cudaMemset(d_output,0,inputWidth*inputHeight*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&FI, inputWidth * inputHeight * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));
    cudaMemset(FI,0,inputWidth*inputHeight*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));

    // Copy input data from host to device using cudaMemcpy2D
    cudaMemcpy2D(d_input, inputWidth * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex), h_input, inputWidth * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex), inputWidth * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex), inputHeight, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Define block and grid dimensions
    dim3 blockDim(1, 1); 
    dim3 gridDim;
    gridDim.y = inputHeight/blockDim.y+((inputHeight%blockDim.y)==0? 0:1);
    gridDim.x = inputWidth/blockDim.x+((inputWidth%blockDim.x)==0? 0:1);

    cout<<"gridDim.x: "<<gridDim.x<<" gridDim.y: "<<gridDim.y<<"\n";
    cout<<"blockDim.x: "<<blockDim.x<<" blockDim.y: "<<blockDim.y<<"\n";
 
    // Launch the kernel
    cufftExecZ2Z(planZ2Z, d_input, FI, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    fftshift<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(FI,inputHeight,inputWidth, true);
    fftshift<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(FI,inputHeight,inputWidth, false);
    cufftExecZ2Z(planIZ2Z, FI, d_output, CUFFT_INVERSE);


  // Copy the result back to the host using cudaMemcpy2D
   cudaMemcpy(h_output,d_output,inputWidth*inputHeight*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  printf("\nOutput dims of image: (%d,%d) \n",inputHeight,inputWidth);
    

  double max = h_output[0].x;
  double min = h_output[0].x;

  for(int i=0;i<inputHeight;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<inputWidth;j++)
    {
      if(h_output[j + i*inputWidth].x>max)
        max = h_output[j + i*inputWidth].x;
      if(h_output[j+ i*inputWidth].x<min)
         min = h_output[j + i*inputWidth].x;
    }

  }

//print double max and min value
printf("\n\nMax value: %f\n",max);
printf("\nMin value: %f\n",min);


//write the value of output_res in file using fp file descriptor
fp.open("output.txt",ios::out);

for(int i=0;i<inputHeight;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<inputWidth;j++)
        fp<< round((h_output[i*inputWidth+j].x - min) * (in_max - in_min) / (max - min) + 0)<<" ";
        
    fp<<"\n";
} 
//close fp file descriptor
fp.close();


// Convert the padded output to OpenCV Mat for visualization or further processing
cv::Mat outputImage(inputHeight, inputWidth, CV_8UC1);

for (int i = 0; i < inputHeight; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputWidth; ++j) {
        outputImage.at<uchar>(i, j) = round((h_output[i*inputWidth+j].x - min) * (in_max - in_min) / (max - min) + 0);
      }
}

  // Find minimum and maximum values
  in_max=  static_cast<int>(outputImage.at<uchar>(0, 0));
  in_min = static_cast<int>(outputImage.at<uchar>(0, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < outputImage.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < outputImage.cols; ++j) {
            int pixel_value = static_cast<int>(outputImage.at<uchar>(i, j));

            if (pixel_value < in_min) {
                    in_min = pixel_value;
            }

            if (pixel_value > in_max) {
                    in_max = pixel_value;
            }
        }
    }

  printf("height : %d, width %d", inputHeight,inputWidth);
  printf("\nMax value: %d\n",in_max);
  printf("\nMin value: %d\n",in_min);


   // Display or save the padded image using OpenCV as needed
   imwrite("output.jpg",outputImage);


    // Cleanup
    delete[] h_input;
    delete[] h_output;
    cudaFree(d_input);
    cudaFree(d_output);
    cudaFree(FI);
    cufftDestroy(planZ2Z);
    cufftDestroy(planIZ2Z);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Input image]

[image: Output image]

Comment: Standard debugging techniques apply here: why don't you start with a single pixel, where the FFT can be calculated by hand and compared to what your program does. Then work your way up to more complicate signals (lines, squares, shaded squares, etc.)

Comment: @Hilmar After debugging, I can assert that the problem lies in the ffshift function because I am finding the center of the Fourier spectrum in the case of an odd size. How can I deal with this situation? How can I obtain an even size from an odd size? In the case of a padding operation, I always end up with an odd size!